# Load data async on client only

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

In my Nuxt3 application I need to fetch some data asynchronously only the client side. Since I need that data very often and I don't have to respect changes I want to cache it and provide it to all of my components. What is the best way to do this? I thought of a composable like this:

```
let data: ExternalData | null = null;

export default async function () {
  if (data !== null) return data;
  data = await loadData();

  return data;
}
```

Now I can use this function in my components like this:

```
onMounted(async () => {
  const data = await useExternalData();
  // ...
});
```

My problem with this is that the component is handling the "only on the client" requirement. I could still call the function on the server side. Is there a way to let the composable handle this? I would also like to use the data in non async functions. I would prefer a call like:

```
const data = useExternalData();
```

How can I archive both these things?